# Is Fiware Cephues obsolete?

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-cep

Fiware Cepheus home page says that its branch is archived and 'read only' now.
https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus
So does it mean:
1. There would be no future support and development in this community?
2. As alternative we should use 'Perseo' as its similar in functionality
   https://perseo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

In general, archiving a GitHub project means that "the project is no longer actively maintained.https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-archiving-repositories

The Fiware Cepheus page also states that "no new features will be added, nor issues fixed by the original team." So this means option 1 is the answer to your question.

There exists 21 forks of this project, so perhaps the community is moving over to one of those?

I am not familiar with 'Perseo', so I cannot tell you if option 2 is a good solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, further information can be found in the [FIWARE 7.4 Release Note](https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue/releases/tag/FIWARE_7.4)

> As announced at the Porto Global Summit 2018, five generic enablers
>   were placed under analysis and have subsequently been removed:
>
> - Proton, 3D-UI, FiVES, Cepheus, Aeron IoT Broker
>
> **Perseo** is the now the
>   preferred generic enabler for complex event processing, replacing
>   Proton and Cepheus. 3D-UI. FiVES and Aeron are no longer seen to be a
>   good fit with the FIWARE project.

If you want to use Complex Event Processing you are left with two choices:

1. Convert your project to use [Perseo](https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-core/) and continue to enjoy community support and development.
2. Continue to use an archived CEP processor, fork it and make further bug fixes on your own.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable comments.